# Adding more info to Laravel's auth user

Tags: authentication, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to add some more information to the user variable I am getting back from Auth::user()

To be more detailed, I have a Many-to-Many relationship to a "Privileges" table. As the name suggests, that table holds specific privileges a user can have.  In the pivot table, I just hold the the user_id and privilege_id.  I have the necessary models set up and everything works fine if I do this in my before filter:

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
$user->priviledges()->get();
```

Now, I would really like to avoid querying every single time I want to find the privileges and would like to have Laravel's Auth class include the privilege information, so that when I do

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

I can do a

```
$user->privileges;
```

to get an array of all privileges the user has.

Any suggestions for the best approach?

Comment: hi @Steve what was you solution to this problem. The link below did not help me.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm no Laravel pro, but i think this will solve your problem: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1652

Comment: the link has been deleted, please update your answer

Comment: This answer did nothing to help me find a solution to my issue. The link is dead with no explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The link to the answer above is not working. However, I found another solution [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-26-2014-how-to-add-additional-data-in-auth) which worked for me as follows:

First I created a model called EmailPref.php in my own case;

app/model/EmailPref.php

```
class EmailPref extends Eloquent {
      protected $table = 'email_pref';

      public function user()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('User');
      }
}
```

and then I created a relationship (in my own case) in the User model like so;

app/model/User.php

```
    public function emailPref()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('EmailPref');
    }
```

I subsequently referenced it anywhere required within my application like so:

```
    Auth::user()->emailPref;
```

Hence, I was able to add more information to the Auth user.

Comment: This may be the best answer, but I wish Laravel would simply return these relationships along with Auth::user()'s return value, because I have that Auth::user() call all over my project in different controllers.